# How to use Newton's second law to derive conservation of momentum and how to use derive conservation of momentum to derive the second law?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws, calculus

I know if taking the integral of $F=ma$, then I can get $p=mv$.
I'm weak in calculus, so I wondered how to do this exactly.

Is there anything wrong in my logic below?

> \begin{align}\int F\left(t\right)\,{\rm d}t&=\int ma\,{\rm d}t \\
> &=m\int a\left(t\right)\,{\rm d}t
> \end{align}
>   where by definition, $\int F\,{\rm d}t=p$ and $\int a\,{\rm d}t=v$. Plug these in above, I get,
>   $$p=mv$$

Equivalently, how to derive from  $m_1a_1=m_1a_1$ to $m_2v_2=m_2v_2$?

Can I do

> Since
>   $$a_1=\frac{{\rm d}v_1}{{\rm d}t_1},\quad a_2=\frac{{\rm d}v_2}{{\rm d}t_2}\tag{1}$$
>   and
>   $$m_1a_1=m_2a_2\tag{2}$$
>   Plug (1) into (2), then get
>   $$
> m_1\frac{{\rm d}v_1}{{\rm d}t_1}=m_2\frac{{\rm d}v_2}{{\rm d}t_2}\tag{3}
> $$
>   where ${\rm d}t_1={\rm d}t_2$. Then plug this into (3) to get,
>   $$m_1{\rm d}v_1=m_2{\rm d}v_2$$
>   With $v_1={\rm d}v_1$ and $v_2={\rm d}v_2$, therefore
>   $$m_1v_1=m_2v_2$$

Comment: The second law isn't $F = m a$, but $\sum F = \dot{p}$

Answer (score 1):

You are showing how force and momentum are related but are not showing momentum is conserved. I will show you a proof for 2 particles and you can generalize it for more.

Consider that $F_{12}$ and $F_{21}$ are the forces acting from 1 on 2 and vice versa. Then (using what you have derived that $F=\dot p$)

$$F = F_{12} + F_{21} + F_{ext} = \dot p$$

Where the last term is from any external forces. Then invoking the 1st law,if the frame is inertial that last term is zero.

Additionally, invoke the 3rd law st $F_{12} = -F_{21}$.

Then $\dot p = 0$ or integrating both sides $p = C $ where $C$ is some constant. So momentum is conserved.